# eclipselink jpa entity is not presented as a table in db

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to make a test project work using eclipselink jpa, but I've met an awkward problem every time I am trying to persist Poll object in the database. It works fine with, for example, User class object. I think, that probably I have a problem with ManyToMany annotations.
So, I have four Entity classes:

Poll.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Polls")
public class Poll implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String title;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date expirationDate;
private String description;
private boolean expired;
private boolean show = false;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "poll")
private List<Option> options;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "polls")
@JoinTable(name = "POLL_USER")
private List<User> users;

public Poll() {
}

public Poll(String title, Date expirationDate, String description,
        boolean expired, boolean show) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    this.description = description;
    this.expired = expired;
    this.show = show;
}

public Poll(String title, Date expirationDate, String description,
        boolean expired, boolean show, List<Option> options,
        List<User> users) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    this.description = description;
    this.expired = expired;
    this.show = show;
    this.options = options;
    this.users = users;
}
```

Option.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Options")
public class Option implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private int voteCount = 0;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "POLL_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Poll poll;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "option")
    private List<Vote> votes;

    public Option() {
    }

    public Option(String text, int voteCount) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public Option(String text, int voteCount, Poll poll, List<Vote> votes) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        this.poll = poll;
        this.votes = votes;
    }
```

Vote.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Votes")
public class Vote implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long vid;
    private String comment;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "OPTION_ID", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Option option;

    public Vote() {
    }

    public Vote(String comment) {
        super();
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Vote(String comment, User user, Option option) {
        super();
        this.comment = comment;
        this.user = user;
        this.option = option;
    }
```

User.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private Long groupId;
    private String email;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Poll> polls;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Vote> votes;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String login, Long groupId, String email) {
        super();
        this.login = login;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public User(String login, Long groupId, String email, List<Poll> polls,
            List<Vote> votes) {
        super();
        this.login = login;
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.email = email;
        this.polls = polls;
        this.votes = votes;
    }
```

There is an error I am receivening:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW, TITLE) VALUES (351, 'Just testing', '2012-09-21 01:49:42', 1, 1, 'My first' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: INSERT INTO Polls (ID, DESCRIPTION, EXPIRATIONDATE, EXPIRED, SHOW, TITLE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(Poll [id=351, title=My first poll, expirationDate=Fri Sep 21 01:49:42 CEST 2012, description=Just testing, expired=true, show=true])
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence-unit name="company" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>logic.Poll</class>
        <class>logic.Option</class>
        <class>logic.Vote</class>
        <class>logic.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eclipselink_example" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="output.log" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="JavaLogger" />
            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->

            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-and-drop-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

After compiling it, i have five tables in db:
Options, SEQUENCE, Users, Users_Polls and Votes. I can't understand, where is Polls table.
Sorry for so many letters, hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your **Poll.java**

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "poll_user", joinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "poll_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns =
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<User> users;
```

And Inside your **User.java**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private List<Poll> polls;
```

Also don't forget to have **getters and setters for your variables**

**REVISION**

Firstly I would changed all the:

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`

to:

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

And I would check that you don't have variables that are RESERVED WORDS in Mysql.

For example:

Inside **Poll.java** you have:

`private boolean show;` but **SHOW** is a reserved word in MySQL

Comment: I already have all getters, setters, hash(), equals() and toString() methods implemented, just didn't write it here to save place.
I did as you said, now i have following error:
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'eclipselink_example.SEQUENCE' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
 bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")

I don't know, why does program need this SEQUENCE table at all

Comment: Well the Error is about your table SEQUENCE not Existing when trying to do an Update and I don't see it in your persistence.xml

Comment: I had table SEQUENCE every time i was working with jpa, it is the table where are stored id keys for entities with @GeneratorValue id's or something. This table is generated by eclipselink, not by me.

Comment: Huh? I have never seen JPA creating a TABLE I don't specify on the persistence or an annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) is basically the annotation to tell the id for the entity, and shouldn't create a separate table of ids?

Comment: Try to use @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) instead of GenerationType.AUTO

Comment: You can see my code, i have neither entities with such name (SEQUENCE) nor such tables joined through annotations. So why would program need table SEQUENCE at all? I don't know.

Comment: Now i have new error:

`javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'eclipselink_example.Users' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: INSERT INTO Users (EMAIL, GROUPID, LOGIN) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
 bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(User [id=null, login=braveleg, groupId=23, email=golyakov.artem@gmail.com])`

Comment: I think this comment is getting to chatty, and you don't have enough reputation for chat do want help through email?

Answer (score 0):

I think, [EclipseLink JPA](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/PrimaryKey) will be helpful your `ID Generation` problem. If you use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` it is depend on database. Good Luck!
As much as possiblem, `GenerationType.TABLE`, it will be independent database